# Facebook explorer API not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Three weeks ago (around 15/05/17) , I was able to use the Facebook API explorer to read my own inbox. 
`me/inbox`

The version that I used was v2.3 which is currently deprecated for public usage but still worked properly when I use it with my own account.

Today, I get this error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#298) You must be a developer of the application",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 298,
    "fbtrace_id": "DfFysTKlP/9"
  }
}
```

The message of this error is a bit confusing because obviously, the API explorer is not a my application.  Is this a bug or a facebook update?

Comment: Notice how it says "Application:" with a dropdown next to it in the top right corner ...?

Comment: @CBroe Exactly, and it's written Graph API Explorer beside. Before it worked...

Comment: _"Exactly, and it's written Graph API Explorer beside."_ - yes, that's how dropdowns work - they show one value, until you _chose another_. Or are you trying to say that you don't even have your own application?

Comment: @CBroe  "Or are you trying to say that you don't even have your own application?" As I said in my question, I am not trying to test my application. I am using the API explorer to run the above syntax. Before it worked. I didn't needed to create an app

Comment: So were is the confusion then? They just closed a loophole. It would still work for you and your own Facebook account, if you had an app that you are developer of - an app old enough, that is. Because any app you create now won't be able to use the old API version where access to the user inbox was still possible any more.